# Why Laravel 8 mutator doesn`t work properly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I try update model, but result for active always stay as 0

**model**

```
class GasStation extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'active'];    
    public function setActiveAttibute($value){
        $this->attributes['active'] = ($this->attributes['active'] === 'on') ? 1 : 0;
    }

}
```

**controller method**

```
public function create(Request $request) {   
        $postContent = $request->all();
        $instance = GasStation::create($postContent);
}
```

What i`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the $value variable, $this->attributes['active'] contains the old value of the attribute.

```
class GasStation extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'active'];    
    public function setActiveAttibute($value){
        $this->attributes['active'] = ($value === 'on') ? 1 : 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you, but this was a different problem